# Get a specific value from a string in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to get some value from a string. For example:

```
String string= "Name: armand," + "Age: 22," + "etc";
```

How can i get for example the name using regular expressions?

I am very bad with regex , so i cant figure out how to solve this.

Comment: So does your string look like this? `"Name: armandAge: 22"`...

Comment: You match it to everything after name up to a quote

Comment: Exactly there does not seem to be any delimeter between fields.

Comment: Imagine storing this in the database in one column(shiver);)

Comment: Sorry its actualy look like this Name:armand,Age:22,etc. But i am very bad in regex, this is hard for me to solve.

Comment: What have you tried.  There are sites and programs that will help you build a regular expression.  You can also simply read how one works and build it yourself.

Comment: @ArmandNdizigiye - You should update your question otherwise it likely will be locked since your questin is currently very poor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you really want to do, for example if you only want to get the value of a given key, given that key and value are separated by colon and key/value are separated by comma, you can just split in this way string first by comma and then by colon :

```
String[] couple = string.split(",");

 for(int i =0; i < couple.length ; i++) {
    String[] items =couple[i].split(":");
    items[0]; //Key
    items[1]; //Value
}
```

If you want to do it with a regular expression you can do in this way :

```
    String string = "Name:armand,Age:22,";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+?):(\\w+?),");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String key = matcher.group(1);
        String value = matcher.group(2);

        System.out.println("Key : " + key + " value : " + value);
    }
```

Comment: thanks. Using split is definetly easier. I realize know,that i have to study more about regex :).

Answer (score 3):

> Sorry its actualy look like this Name:armand,Age:22,etc. But i am very
>   bad in regex, this is hard for me to solve.

Given `String s = "Name:armand,Age:22";`

Here is a hint:

`s.split(",")[0].split(":")` will give you `armand`,

`s.split(",")[1].split(":")` will give you `22`

no regular expression knowledge needed.

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think  “I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems. - Jamie Zawinski

Comment: You could change this to make use of `substring`. The `split` method treats any input as a RegEx and attempts to compile it, whether you meant it or not.